# Displaying data in a ListView

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.forms

After many adventures, I was able to display my data in my ListView, except that the display is not what I expected as can be seen in the image.
[View of the customer list display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFdgW.jpg)

My code xaml.cs

```
private void VoirBdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (Connecté)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ps_customer", cn);
            using (MySqlDataReader Lire = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var data = new List<MesClients>();
                while (Lire.Read())
                {
                    string ID = Lire["id_customer"].ToString();
                    string firstname = Lire["firstname"].ToString();
                    string lastname = Lire["lastname"].ToString();
                    data.Add(new MesClients(firstname, lastname));
                }
                clientsbdd.ItemsSource = data;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayAlert("Infos:", "Plantage", "Ok");
        }
    }
```

What did I miss to not make a good display please?

Comment: You should clarify your problem. Add output, errors and so on. Afterwards you may receive possible solutions.

Comment: It was my to.string method which wasn't well defined, now it's ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are reading the data from the db but not actually doing anything with it - you assign the data to local variables but are not using them

```
while (Lire.Read())
{
   string ID = Lire["id_customer"].ToString();
   string Prénom = Lire["firstname"].ToString();
   string Nom = Lire["lastname"].ToString();
            
   clientsbdd.ItemsSource.ToString();
}
```

instead, do this (you will need to create a class `MyClass` to model your data)

```
var data = new List<MyClass>();

while (Lire.Read())
{
   string ID = Lire["id_customer"].ToString();
   string Prénom = Lire["firstname"].ToString();
   string Nom = Lire["lastname"].ToString();
            
   data.Add(new MyClass { ID = ID, Prenom = Prenom, Nom = Nom});
}

clientsbdd.ItemsSource = data;
```

if you are passing values via the constructor instead of using properties, then do this

```
data.Add(new MyClass(ID, Prenom, Nom));
```

Comment: see my expanded example

Comment: Thanks, it's ok, i see my data.